# Good idea to use cucumber for Web Automation?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm currently running Selenium automation on Junit.

After seeing the power of Cucumber , I thought of using it. Is really Cucumber can help much in Web Automation?

Suggestion will be greatful

Comment: This is an interesting article;  http://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/please-don-t-use-cucumber

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber is not a Silver bullet, but it has helped me to automate web application testing with ease.
I used it as an automation framework with Watir-webdriver. It was one of my successful projects.
Remember to have your steps as atomic instead of depending on other steps.